# How to verify call on setter in kotlin using mockito?

Tags: mockito, kotlin, setter, verify

```
interface LoginDisplay {
    var username: String
    var password: String
}


class LoginActivityLoginDisplay : LoginDisplay {

    override var username: String
        get() = usernameEditView.text.toString()
        set(value) {
            usernameEditView.setText(value)
        }

    override var password: String
        get() = passwordEditView.text.toString()
        set(value) {
            passwordEditView.setText(value)
        }

}
```

This is the example of code I'd like to test with Mockito as follows:

```
verify(contract.loginDisplay).username
```

Tricky thing is - that in this call i can only verify getter of field username, meanwhile I'd like to test call on setter of this field.

Any help?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's simpler than you think. Calling:

```
verify(contract.loginDisplay).username = ""
```

will have the result you want. Setter `setUsername` on the mock of `contract.loginDisplay` will be called.

Comment: Also be sure to check that the verified property is marked as **open**... took me a while before actually reading mockito message about that

Comment: Is it possible to assert that the setter was _not_ called?